# Is there a text effect for Sony Vegas Movie Studio for light reflecting off metal?

Tags: video-editor

I found a picture to illustrate the effect I would like to have. http://www.bugei.com/scart/public/database/repository/images_import/peace/habuchi.jpg

Does anyone know of text effect for this, or another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vegas Movie Studio or Pro versions do not have a text option already set up for this but there are a couple of ways to get what you want.

One way is to make a composite by creating two video tracks one with the text and the other with the image you want to bleed through the text, here are instructions on how to do what is called a 'masking track':

http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/creating_masking_tracks_in_vegas

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add this type of effect using light rays and lens flares on the text.  When I was first learning Vegas I did some YouTube searches to find tutorials. [THIS](http://youtu.be/3HT4Aoqd7M8) video in particular gives you an idea of how to do what you are looking for I believe.